# nuxt - creating child routes for mandatory param route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a folder structure like this:

```
map
-_id
--index.vue
--items.vue
```

When I access the path: `/map/:id/items` it doesn't show the `:id` component. How should I be structuring my files?

Comment: _"it doesn't show the `:id` component"_  could you please explain what this means? Nuxt will create routes with an `:id` parameter. I'm not sure what you mean by _component_

Comment: @Phil So my `index.vue` makes `id` a mandatory param. When I go to the subpath of `items`, it switches completely to the `items` component, rather than have it nested as under `id`

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-nested-routes), it seems you should also have a `map/_id.vue` component

Comment: @Phil But that would turn it into an optional parameter?